# Where is a good starting point for planning Information Architecture for a website?

Tags: architecture, websites, information

I am planning a project to develop and enhance an information architecture for a website.

This will include navigation structures, content classification, metadata etc.

- Where is the best place to start planning this?
- What software can be used to create this (apart from MS Word?)
- Any tips on how to go about designing a structure?
- What should/should not be included?

Hoping you can help.

Comment: What do you think goes into an "Information Architecture"?  Could you suggest an audience and a purpose and some kinds of content that go into this thing?

Comment: Updated the question slightly.

Comment: not much of an update, is it?  Please be more specific about what problem you think this "architecture" will solve.  Who uses it?  What do they do with it?  Words like "navigation structures, content classification, metadata" can mean almost anything. It helps if you provide a use case for this "architecture" thing.

Comment: Did you see my first point about looking for a place to start? The audience is not relevant to finding out ways of going about designing this type of architecture - that's part of the process.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest reading:

- **A List Apart**, especially articles in content tag: http://www.alistapart.com/topics/content/
- Jacob Nielsen't **alertbox**: http://www.useit.com/alertbox/

Comment: and start with the goals of the website, not the technology!